# How do I use Google Play Games in my app?

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am trying to write a game, and I want to use Google Play Games services to share highscores, and maybe do multiplayer. I have researched far and wide, but there isn't anything that I could find to help me. If someone could explain the basics to me or recommend a resource, that would be great.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

The Google Developers website has a whole section dedicated to Google Play Games Services with a tutorial and tons of other useful information: https://developers.google.com/games/services/

Answer (score 1):

You must have a devoloper account and go to https://play.google.com/apps/publish/.

Create an app in the console and go to " Services and API"